# How to replace dot from integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to create a multiple stopwatches in one page, i have found a code online that's working as same as i need, but there's a problem, the integer they're rendering is like 4.03 means 4 is like second and 03 is seconds, i want something like 4:03 or if you can give me any other code which works the same way this code is working, Thanks

i expect the output of 4.03 to be 4:03

```js
var Stopwatch = function(elem, options) {
  
  var timer       = createTimer(),
      startButton = createButton("start", start),
      stopButton  = createButton("stop", stop),
      resetButton = createButton("reset", reset),
      offset,
      clock,
      interval;
  
  // default options
  options = options || {};
  options.delay = options.delay || 1;
 
  // append elements     
  elem.appendChild(timer);
  elem.appendChild(startButton);
  elem.appendChild(stopButton);
  elem.appendChild(resetButton);
  
  // initialize
  reset();
  
  // private functions
  function createTimer() {
    return document.createElement("span");
  }
  
  function createButton(action, handler) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "#" + action;
    a.innerHTML = action;
    a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      handler();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    return a;
  }
  
  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      offset   = Date.now();
      interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
    }
  }
  
  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    }
  }
  
  function reset() {
    clock = 0;
    render(0);
  }
  
  function update() {
    clock += delta();
    render();
  }
  
  function render() {
    timer.innerHTML = clock/1000; 
  }
  
  function delta() {
    var now = Date.now(),
        d   = now - offset;
    
    offset = now;
    return d;
  }
  
  // public API
  this.start  = start;
  this.stop   = stop;
  this.reset  = reset;
};


// basic examples
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("basic");

for (var i=0, len=elems.length; i<len; i++) {
  new Stopwatch(elems[i]);
}


// programmatic examples
var a = document.getElementById("a-timer");
aTimer = new Stopwatch(a);
aTimer.start();

var b = document.getElementById("b-timer");
bTimer = new Stopwatch(b, {delay: 100});
bTimer.start();

var c = document.getElementById("c-timer");
cTimer = new Stopwatch(c, {delay: 456});
cTimer.start();

var d = document.getElementById("d-timer");
dTimer = new Stopwatch(d, {delay: 1000});
dTimer.start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .stopwatch {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .stopwatch span {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
  }
  .stopwatch a {
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Basic example; update every 1 ms</h2>
  
<p>click <code>start</code> to start a stopwatch</p>
  
<pre>
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("basic");
  
for (var i=0, len=elems.length; i&lt;len; i++) {
  new Stopwatch(elems[i]);
}
</pre>
<div class="basic stopwatch"></div>
<div class="basic stopwatch"></div>

<hr>
<h2>Programmatic example</h2>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> despite the varying <code>delay</code> settings, each stopwatch displays the correct time (in seconds)</p>

<pre>
var a = document.getElementById("a-timer");
aTimer = new Stopwatch(a);
aTimer.start();
</pre>
<div class="stopwatch" id="a-timer"></div>1 ms<br>
  
<pre>
var b = document.getElementById("b-timer");
bTimer = new Stopwatch(b, {delay: 100});
bTimer.start();
</pre>
<div class="stopwatch" id="b-timer"></div>100 ms<br>

<pre>
var c = document.getElementById("c-timer");
cTimer = new Stopwatch(c, {delay: 456});
cTimer.start();
</pre>
<div class="stopwatch" id="c-timer"></div>456 ms<br>
  
<pre>
var d = document.getElementById("d-timer");
dTimer = new Stopwatch(d, {delay: 1000});
dTimer.start();
</pre>
<div class="stopwatch" id="d-timer"></div>1000 ms<br>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your current relevant code here

Comment: https://jsbin.com/IgaXEVI/167/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Don't try to get around the restrictions of posting links to external sandbox without entering any code in your question by wrapping those links in a code block. Those restrictions are there for a reason. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial problem. Now we can't even click on the link in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your number into a string, and then use the replace method:

```
val.toString().replace('.', ':');
```

Edit:

How to update your render function :

```
  function render() {
    const timerValue = clock/1000; 
    timer.innerHTML = timerValue.toString().replace('.', ':');
  }
```

Comment: but than it'll not run the timer.

Comment: You only to store the result in a new variable and use this to display it.

Comment: I added the exact code you need to change in your code to make it happen...

Comment: it's not working bro, can you please send me some code example regarding my code which i'm running yet

Comment: I just edited my answer with the exact code you need to change to make this work from your jsfiddle. I'm not sure what more you want.

Comment: No clue why this was down-voted, I've up-voted you 

Comment: sorry bro, i can't find timerValue variable.

Comment: @JackRogers Thanks :D
@JawadAjaz the `timerValue` is defined in the render method. The first line of the method in my answer...

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code to actually be in the question now.

Comment: one more thing bro, i want to get the values of all running timers and add them and render it in an another div. is that possible?